# Twilio Cold Transfer, no queue overflow

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

**Requirement**

Our business requires us to expand the functionality of the transfer feature that is already built in to
Twilio Flex.

**What exists today**

Today's functionality (out of the box) is partially what we need with the `Actions.TransferTask` functions.  The issue with this is that when we choose an agent to cold transfer to, and they're not available, the call gets put back in to a queue and picked up by the next available agent.  This seems completely counter intuitive to how I would expect it to work as I would expect that call to go to voicemail if the agent is unable to pick up.

**What we tried**

We have logged a support ticket with Twilio to no avail.  Any attempts to use the `StartConferenceCall` won't work because we're on an active call.  Twilio functions' `Dial` doesn't seem to work as I don't seem to have access to my current call.  (`Dial` is meant for calls that are about to happen?)  But `Dial` seems to be the only process that allows `digits` to be passed.  Therefore, conferences & participants don't seem to be the answer either.

What we do have though is a phone number that will end up in our primary work flow and if the incoming number is the aforementioned number, we skip the voice prompts, accept digits and redirect to the agent.  This part works.

**What we need**

We're looking for a Twilio function or plugin `Action` (or some other method that I'm unaware of) that can cold transfer a call to another agent with no over flow to a queue (let it get picked up by voicemail).